# UIImage rotation and orientation issue

Tags: objective-c, rotation, uiimage, cgcontext, uiimageorientation

I'm using standart code to rotate image, but when UIImageRotatation is not equal to 2, the image is rotated not correctly.

Any code to fix UIImageRotation and rotate image by X degrees? Try nearly everything.

```c
NSLog(@"Image orientation %d",self.imageOrientation);
CGSize rotatedSize  = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(self.size, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(degrees)));

if (rotatedSize.width < 0) {
    rotatedSize.width *= -1;
}
if (rotatedSize.height < 0) {
    rotatedSize.height *= -1;
}

// Create the bitmap context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, YES, 0.0);
CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

//   // Rotate the image context
CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, rad(degrees));

// Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2, self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

Comment: I've certainly been able to do it using transforms.  It takes some experimentation.  Among other things, turn off auto-layout on the containing views.

Comment: I need it to rotate image correctly becouse i use the rotated image for croping. Do you have some code ? Thank you for any help

Comment: Like I said, it takes some experimentation.

Comment: tried everything for last 5 hours, and no result...